Databricks Asset Bundles: use Variables in Target Section
I have the following Databricks Asset Bundle:
bundle:
  name: cat

variables:
  workspace_url:
    description: Name of the workspace
    default: "https://xxx.next"

include:
  - resources/*.yml
    
targets:
  test:
    workspace:
      host: ${var.workspace_url}

I would like to use the variable in the target section. However, when running validation I get:
Validating the Databricks Asset Bundles...
Error: failed during request visitor: parse "https://${var.workspace_url}": invalid character "{" in host name

What I am doing wrong?
